# How to best join table using indexes

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

The following query is running very slow...

```
SELECT
   CONCAT(users.first_name, ' ', users.last_name) AS user_name,
   leads.first_name AS first_name,
   comments.*,
FROM comments
   INNER JOIN users ON 
      users.id = comments.user_id
   INNER JOIN leads ON 
      leads.id = comments.lead_id AND 
      leads.company_id = 1 
 ORDER BY 
    `sort` DESC, 
     reply ASC, 
     id ASC 
LIMIT 80,20
```

leads table has ~ 8000 records
users table has ~ 300 records
comments table has ~ 500,000 records

I have an index on leads.id, comments.lead_id, leads.company_id, users.id, and comments.user_id, comments.sort, comments.reply, comments.id

Can someone explain how to optimize this query?

[Screenshot of query EXPLAIN](https://image.ibb.co/cdJ5MK/Screen_Shot_2018_08_07_at_3_22_21_PM.png)

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` for user to comments?

Comment: is a composite index for all those field or simple index for each one?

Comment: for some reason I cant see the picture

Comment: **what is slow?** Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: Updated link to EXPLAIN screenshot

Comment: Since you are doing a left join, I would think it is expected that everything from the left would be returned, therefore, of course it is not optimal.

Comment: Is `company_id` a `integer`? If so `leads.company_id = '1' ` is problematic as it may force `mysql` to cast every `company_id` to CHAR() in order to perform the comparison to the string literal `'1'`. Instead: `leads.company_id = 1 ` which should allow the condition to make use of the index.

Comment: @JNevill updated to use integer ... no performance change

Comment: @Hozikimaru Changed to use INNER JOIN ... no performance increase

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I am using simple index for each. Would there be a benefit to using a composite index?

Comment: Yes, build your query by small steps. Check `EXPLAIN PLAN` add proper index, then add second table check plan again, then add sort. and so on

Answer (score 1):

Move `leads` to first in the `from` list:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(users.first_name, ' ', users.last_name) AS user_name,
  leads.first_name AS first_name,
  comments.*
FROM leads
INNER JOIN comments ON 
  comments.lead_id = leads.id
INNER JOIN users ON 
  users.id = comments.user_id
WHERE leads.company_id = 1
ORDER BY 
  `sort` DESC, 
  reply ASC, 
  id ASC 
LIMIT 80,20
```

This allows the index on `leads(company)` to immediately filter out as many rows as possible before joining to the other tables.

The performance increase should be about `1/(fraction of leads with company_id = 1)`

Comment: All the leads at the moment have the company ID of 1... that is for an upcoming upgrade.

Comment: Inner join is commutative and associative, so I don't think the order should make a difference.

Comment: @barmar theoretically yes, but I’ve seen this kind of change make a difference on occasion (I don’t trust the optimizer!)